# (Sitecore) After publishing or saving in content editor, half screen freeze

Tags: browser, save, editor, sitecore, freeze

Does anyone have the same problem? 
Normally, we have 7-8 persons edit content at same time in Sitecore content editor. And we will save and publish. 
Sometimes, we find our browser half screen freeze. We only can logout and login again. Then we can keep working on editing. 
It happens on every one in the team, and it happens on different browsers, IE8, 9, Chrome. 
And this is not caused by server performance. Server performance is always good.

Does anyone can give some idea?

Sitecore version is 6.4.1

I wonder whether this is related to cache setting or thread.

Comment: I would suggest you contact Sitecore support on this, as this seems like a Sitecore bug.

Comment: I am not sure but if this is only in chrome then you have to check this link - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527